# Not able to redirect to home page after login in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'

angular.module('fffff', ['ionic', 'chart.js', 'ui.router']) 
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

//Multiple Controllers Approach Start
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
      // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
      // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
      // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
      //alert("stateProvider"+$stateProvider.state);       
      //LoginCtrl HomeCtrl

      $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
                url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',      
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })

      //<p>Hello, world!</p>
      $stateProvider
        .state('fhcentral', {
                url: '/fhcentral',
        templateUrl: 'fh_central.html', 
        controller: 'fhCtrl'
        })   

      // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
      //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/employees');
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');    
})


//Multiple Controllers Approach End
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $http, $stateParams, $state) {

  $scope.errMsg = "";   
  $scope.response = "";
  $scope.login = function () {  
    if(!$scope.uname) {
            $scope.errMsg = "Please enter your username !"; 
            $state.go('login'); 
    }

        if(!$scope.pwd) {
            $scope.errMsg = "Please enter your password !"; 
            $state.go('login');   
        }

        if(!$scope.uname && !$scope.pwd) {
            $scope.errMsg = "Please enter your username and password !"; 
            $state.go('login');   
        }

        // Here Need the Validation        
        if($scope.uname && $scope.pwd) 
        {
         $http.get('http://10.10.10.227:8080/DataAnalysisPOC/Login/userLogin', {
                    params: {
                        userId: '123456',
                        authCode: "123456",
                        emailId: $scope.uname,
                        password: $scope.pwd
                    }
                 })
            .success(function (data,status) { 

               //User does not exist
               var response = angular.toJson(data);
               var response = JSON.parse(response);
               //alert(response.LoginDetail[0].message);            

               if(response.LoginDetail[0].message == "User does not exist") {
                   $scope.errMsg = "User does not exist !"; 
                   $state.go('login');                  
               }

               if(response.LoginDetail[0].message == "Password Incorrect") {
                   $scope.errMsg = "Password Incorrect !"; 
                   $state.go('login');                  
               }

               if(response.LoginDetail[0].message == "Password Matched") {   

           //$scope.errMsg = "Password Matched !";                  
                   window.localStorage.clear();                   
                   window.localStorage['username'] = $scope.uname; 
                   window.localStorage['pwd'] = $scope.pwd;               
                   window.localStorage['pgmId'] = response.LoginDetail[0].pgmId;
                   window.localStorage['email'] = response.LoginDetail[0].email;
                   window.localStorage['userId'] = response.LoginDetail[0].userId;
                   window.localStorage['roleCode'] = response.LoginDetail[0].roleCode;
                   window.localStorage['roleId'] = response.LoginDetail[0].roleId;
                   window.localStorage['accId'] = response.LoginDetail[0].accId;
                   window.localStorage['userType'] = response.LoginDetail[0].userType;
                   //$scope.succMsg == "Welcome to Home Page"; 
           alert("Hi"); 
                   $state.go('fhcentral'); 
           //$location.path("/fhcentral"); 
           //$location.path("/fhcentral");
           //$location.transitionTo('/fhcentral');                 
               }
               //User does not exist
               //return false;
               //var message = response.LoginDetail[0].message; 
            });  
        }   
  }     
})

.controller('fhCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $http, $stateParams, $state) {
  alert("Hi");
})
```

In the above app.js,  $state.go('fhcentral'); piece of code is not working  for redirection .. Can anyone help me with the solution ?

I have been trying to find out the solution for the above issue, but not able to find out ... Pls help me out ...

Do I have to install any addon or plugin to enable redirection in the basic installation of ionic framework ??

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Does your "hi" gets invoked? and do where do you store ur .html file? Is it under some folders?

Comment: Yes ... Hi gets invoked and .html file is not saved inside any folder ...